# I purchased a box of car fuses ranging from 5 to 40 amps from EBAY. I want to test the fuse rating using dummy loads

Tags: fuses, tester

I purchased a box of car fuses from EBAY.  When testing the current draw on a new tire inflation pump, rated at 40 amps. I tested it using a 30 amp eBay fuse.  The fuse started smoking, the fuse's plastic housing melted and burned but the fusible link did not blow. I want to build a simple resistive dummy load to test each fuse rating 5 to 40 amps.

P.S. I only buy fuses from a reputable source now but I want to test them anyway.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: I'm just glad to read that you performed testing!! There's a whole area of physics design that goes into a well-designed fuse. I only have read a little about the topic, but I can tell from what I read that there are a number of ODEs and PDEs and empirical materials science that goes into it. There's a key simplifying concept called the *specific action integral*, which is what a fuse targets. But bottom line here is that there's no reason to continue testing, except to see if your test was exceptional. But even then I'd throw them away. The whole point is such behavior shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Thank you, I like to test because I need  to know the fuse actually does it job.   Cheers.

Comment: Thanks  GodJihyo well pointed out.

Comment: You already know what you need to do to test them. Build a resistive dummy load. We can't provide full schematics to something like that, plenty online. Or buy a pre-built one. Or use a current limited bench supply that can support these ratings.

Comment: You can test the fuse blowing characteristics compared to [datasheets](https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/automotive/datasheets/fuses/passenger-car-and-commercial-vehicle/blade-fuses/littelfuse_mini_datasheet.pdf) and test that the materials conform to UL94 flammability ratings (the procedures are simple, but you need access to the  standards). Use a leadcheck swab to test for Pb content. That will get you some of the way there.

Comment: Stupid question: how much money would you be losing it you just brought the ebay-bought fuses to the recycling? Compare that with the cost of a measurement setup safe and deterministic enough to trust your tested fuses enough that you want to take the risk of them being the thing that didn't stop the fire in a car. I'll be honest, if definitely throw them away and just buy fuses from a source I could trust without testing.

Comment: So, a rack of headlamp bulbs switchable in parallel will be at least controllable but your connections must be clean and tight.

Comment: If you only buy fuses from a reputable source then why have you bought peebay fuses?

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume you are using a 12V car battery as a source of current. The circuit you would be using to test these fuses, might look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCCDle.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The highest rating of fuse you wish to test is 40A, and so we will need to be able to pass current up to, say, 50A maximum. Using Ohm's law, we can calculate the resistance required between the battery's terminals that would pass 50A:

$$ R_{TOTAL} = \frac{V}{I} = \frac{12V}{50A} = 0.24\Omega = 240m\Omega $$

This represents the combined resistance of all elements around the loop, which is the sum of the resistances of switch SW1, Fuse F, dummy load R, and (importantly) all the physical electrical joints connecting these elements together in series, and the wires between them.

That may sound easy, but those connections will need to be impeccable, because even a few milliohms (thousandths of an ohm) will upset your results. It is surprisingly hard to make such good connections. You will have to solder them, or employ screwed clamps or other such techniques.

Any long runs of wiring connecting everything together will have to be heavy gauge. For example, if we estimate the total length of wire around the loop to be 1m, then according to [tables like this](https://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/AWG.phtml), then 1m of AWG 20 cable will have a resistance of 30mΩ which is a significant chunk of the 240mΩ.

The switch will be another current bottle-neck. You will require your switch to have resistance *significantly* lower than 240mΩ, not only because this resistance will affect current flow, but also because it will dissipate power, which can damage the switch through heating. Consider using an automotive relay (rated 50A or more, and don't forget the diode) to keep switching resistance to a minimum:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feAuV5.png)</sup>

Here the switch is required to pass less than 1A of current, to power the relay coil, and its own resistance no longer factors into the calculations. It is now the relay's contact resistance which you must consider, which will typically be only a few milliohms.

Even the battery will have some internal resistance, which will reduce current flow. For a regular car battery, this can be anywhere from 10mΩ to 100mΩ depending on charge state and battery health.

I will refer to the combined "parasitic" resistance of all these elements combined (not including the deliberate resistance R) around the loop as \$R_P\$, which you will have to measure somehow, and factor in to your experimental results if you wish to be able to trust them.

To measure the loop's parasitic resistance \$R_P\$, we must pass a current, and take some measurements:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0H38v.png)</sup>

We have introduced \$R=10\Omega\$, and are measuring battery voltage \$V_{BAT}\$ on VM2, and resistor voltage \$V_R\$ on VM1.

We need a couple of measurements for battery voltage, unloaded and loaded. With the switch *open* (battery completely unloaded), measure the battery voltage (VM2 above). This will tell you the battery's EMF, which I shall call \$V_{BAT(EMF)}\$. Then close the switch (briefly) and read VM1 to obtain resistor voltage \$V_R\$.

From this information, we can calculate current \$I\$ around the loop using Ohm's law:

$$ I = \frac{V_R}{R} = \frac{12.41}{10\Omega} = 1.24A $$

Using Kirchhoff's Voltage Law, we can find the effective voltage \$V_P\$ lost across all parasitic resistive elements in the loop consisting of the battery's own internal resistance, resistances of the switch, wiring and fuse. This will be:

$$ V_P = V_{BAT(EMF)} - V_R = 12.6V - 12.41V = 0.19V $$

Now, with Ohm's law, we calculate \$R_P\$:

$$ R_P = \frac{V_P}{I} = \frac{0.19V}{1.24A} = 150m\Omega $$

Now you are ready to find the resistance \$R\$ needed to pass whatever current \$I\$ you desire. Total resistance around the loop will be \$R + R_P\$, and our application of Ohm's law will look like this:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R + R_P &= \frac{V_{BAT(EMF)}}{I} \\ \\
R &= \frac{V_{BAT(EMF)}}{I} - R_P \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Unfortunately, as the battery discharges and heats up, you will find that \$R_P\$ changes, and so you'll need to perform the procedure above to recalculate R_P at regular intervals.

You might have guessed already that if \$R_P\$ is changing, then there's no fixed resistance \$R\$ that corresponds to any particular current. All that hard work above is really just to show that this approach (using resistive loads) is probably not a very efficient way to produce a known current. I'm starting to think that this idea won't work very well.

You might get lucky, and have \$R_P\$ very low, if you used the most expensive wiring and relay and a brand new battery etc.. Let's say you have \$R_P=50m\Omega\$, and calculate what resistance you need to pass 40A:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R &= \frac{V_{BAT(EMF)}}{I} - R_P \\ \\
&= \frac{12.6}{40A} - 0.05\Omega \\ \\
&= 0.27\Omega \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Now find the power that will be dissipated in this resistance:

$$ P = I^2R = (40A)^2 \times 0.27\Omega = 430W $$

I started writing this answer with the assumption that it might by feasible to do all this, but it's clear by now that there are serious hurdles to jump. I feel a bit silly having failed to perform some simple feasibility calculations prior to starting writing. Still, I'll leave it all here.

It might be possible to achieve 400W of power dissipation if you constructed 0.27Ω by combining many resistances to share that power, but you'll still require some beefy heat sinks, expensive resistors, and probably forced-air cooling. Remember, you might have to wait a couple of seconds for the fuse to blow, during which time all your resistors reach 200°C. It's not looking good.